# Can i run my ant command without build.xml?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ant, war

We have a requirement where we need to execute ant task in order to perform some operation. in local, it works fine but on the server what we do is we make a .war file using an ant and then deploy .war file on tomcat on Linux server, now on the server I just have a .war file no build.xml file. is there any way I can run my ant task without buil.xml but using just war file? please let me know if there is any workaround.

Comment: Can you specify what the task is supposed to do? Ant tasks can also be run programmatically.

Comment: the task is basically calling one method in one class that performs some database entries. @PiotrP.Karwasz

Comment: If that is part of the application logic, you can call it from a `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: thnx @PiotrP.Karwasz, a working example would help me a lot, can you share a link?

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to use a `ServletContextListener`, e.g. [this one](https://mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/).

Comment: If all you want to do is call a method in a class, all your work is going to be in setting up a correct environment with database connections etc. You can do that from a command line insted, ant is not helping you a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not. build.xml contains the definition of what the ant task is meant to do, so without that file ant have no idea what it is you want it to do.

You can copy build.xml to the server and then delete it afterwards. You could also place build.cml inside the war file and then extract it before using it, but that seems to be a really bad idea.

Comment: thnx @Soren Mors for responding, this is new to me, can you tell me where can I place build.xml on a server in order to execute ant commands?

Comment: Wherever you wish to run ant. Ant looks in the current directory for build.xml but can also be told to look elsewhere.